# How to integrate Wordpress with Cakephp?

Tags: wordpress, cakephp-2.0

For my website, i want to use a CMS. I felt `WordPress` is having more features and provides lots of plugins to make our website best. But the problem i am facing is.., how can i use Word Press with `Cakephp` framework?

Comment: have you checked this http://rakesh.tembhurne.com/running-wordpress-blog-from-cakephp/ & http://wordpress.org/support/topic/want-to-integrate-wordpress-into-cakephp?replies=3 and even this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/failing-to-integrate-wp-with-cakephp?replies=10

Answer (score 15):

- Now, the first thing is if you want to integrate WordPress in CakePHP, you have to put that in app/webroot folder. So, put WordPress folder into app/webroot of your CakePHP.
- But cake doesn’t keep the address to http://www.example.com/blog/. It changes address to http://www.example.com/app/webroot/blog/.
- Now open .htaccess file from your CakePHP root directory and replace the content with following lines.

> ```
>  RewriteEngine on
>
>  RedirectMatch temp ^/blog/wp-admin$ http://www.example.com/blog/
>
>  RewriteRule ^blog$ blog/ [L]
>
>  RewriteRule ^blog/wp-admin$ blog/wp-admin/ [L]
>
>  RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
>
>  RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
> ```

Please try this.. may be it will helpful for you..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your WordPress database from CakePHP 2.x, you can use some [models I created](https://github.com/alexbiddle/cakephp-wordpress-plugin).

You can query your data by the usual Cake methods.

```
$this->loadModel('Wordpress.Post');
$this->Post->find('all');
```

This may be useful if you need to do some heavy-lifting with Cake using data from WordPress. Tighter integration is possible, but it takes more work. I've written a [blog post](http://alexbiddle.github.io/2014/11/16/create-unit-tested-wordpress-plugins-with-cakephp.html) that you may find useful.